# Getting empty string or null value from textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to test a simple `<input>` item and then print the contents to the console. I have a textbox and will insert some text with then hoping to see the data printed to the console but this is not happening. I am actually trying to test a more complicated item with the `<input>` being JSON and then reading the fields without knowing what kind of JSON it is or the number of JSON fields.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('my-text-box').value;
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(input);

console.log(document.getElementById('my-text-box').value);

try {
  /*
  message_content = JSON.parse(input);
  
  var message = JSON.parse(input);
  
  for (var key in message) {
    var keyjson = message[key];
    
    if (typeof infoJSON !== "object") {
      console.log(keyjson)
    }
  }
  */
} catch (e) {
  error = true;
  log.error('Something went wrong', e)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="my-text-box"></input>
```

[Here’s a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eqemx218/1813/)

Comment: it should be document.getElementById('my-text-box').value

Comment: Thanks I tried that and still not working; its weird, I used other jsfiddle examples others posted & it does not work for. Almost as if browser settings on my side causing some issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `Element.value()` is not a function, so instead use `Element.value` this is only valid for input elements.

Second, `var input` is always assigned an empty string because it was executed before any character enters the input element, to avoid that use the following :

```
input.addEventListener( 'change', function(){ 
       inputVal = JSON.stringify( this.value ); 
       console.log( inputVal ); 
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first line:

```
 var input = document.getElementById('my-text-box').value();
```

Should be

```
 var input = document.getElementById('my-text-box').value;
```

Since value is a property which is not a function, it is a string.

Comment: I did have this but still not working but still returning empty string. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var textArea = document.getElementById("text");

textArea.addEventListener("change", function() {
    console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

Comment: this works running it here; is there an issue if I am running with jquery (Edge) in order to have console.log work.

Answer (score 0):

To take the value of an input, do it this way

```
console.log(document.getElementById('my-text-box').value);
```